# MediaElement.IsLoaded Lies

Tags: c#, wpf, media

So I've created a slideshow.  The slideshow uses two overlapping media elements which display pictures.  A transition simply means decrementing opacity of the foreground element and incrementing the opacity of the background element.

The problem is a picture is not loaded into the media element fast enough.  This causes stuttering and generally looks bad.  I got the idea that I could just create a tight loop that looks at the MediaElement.IsLoaded property until it becomes true.  It turns out that isLoaded is always true because IsLoaded considers the media element, not the source.

I also thought about MediaElement.DownloadProgress, but it lies too.

Thoughts?

Comment: You should subscribe to the `MediaElement.Loaded` event and handle it accordingly.

Comment: The MediaElement.Loaded event doesn't fire after the media element itself has been loaded.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `Loaded` event and the `IsLoaded` property are general features of all WPF controls derived from `FrameworkElement`.  The `IsLoaded` property becomes `true` and the `Loaded` event is raised when the element is added to the visual tree, not when the content of the element has been displayed.  So `IsLoaded` is the wrong property for what you are trying to detect.

The `Loaded` event is described like this:

> Loaded is usually the last event raised in an element initialization sequence.

On the other hand, `MediaElement` has an event that might meet your needs:

- [MediaElement.MediaOpened Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.mediaelement.mediaopened%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)

which is described like this:

> Occurs when the media stream has been validated and opened, and the file headers have been read.

This sounds like the correct event for your application.

Comment: Beautiful.  Thank you for your answer.  I will make sure to more thoroughly read the MSDN library before asking here in the future.